# Accessing rails application running on VM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtual-machine, webrick

I have a rails application running on a linux VM at localhost:3000 which I can happily access. However, when I try to access the app outwith the VM (Windows) I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in Chrome.

The rails server outputs:

```
ERROR bad URI
ERROR bad Request-Line
```

How am I able to configure my rails app so I can access it outwith the VM.

I am using  ruby 2.1.5, rails 4.1.7 and WEBrick 1.3.1.

Thanks

Comment: I tried clearing the cookies in Chrome as well as running rake tmp:clear and this seemed to solve the problem. Although strangely it took a few server restarts before it appeared to work. I would like to understand this problem better if anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vm uses a different localhost than your computer. Try:

```
 http://10.0.2.2:3000
```

Don't forget to write http!! If that does not work, you will have to go to C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and add:

```
10.0.2.2 outer
```